# Java, how to write a file on the fly

Tags: java

Currently in my application I am storing a bunch of data in memory, and at the end writing it to a file by going through the `ArrayList` and dumping the data into a file pointer.  How can I go about writing the data on the fly, but I don't want it to be stored in some file pointer memory.  I want it to be written to the disk as the application is running.  Trying to keep memory costs at a minimum.  I am ok with a short lecture on how file pointers work in Java too if necessary for an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: so ... what did you try so far to achieve this, code-wise?

Comment: Like I mentioned, storing a bunch of objects in an `ArrayList` and then at the end just using a for each loop to write the data to a file.

Comment: "I want it to be written to the disk as the application is running" - so where's your approach? what's wrong with it?

Comment: Have you thought about adding a layer of abstraction between your application and the in-memory storage? This would let you sandwich in an asynchronous module that writes blocks of data to your file, flushing everything on shutdown

Comment: I have no idea on how to go about writing such a layer of abstraction.  Was hoping to get some help on how to go about this.  @malchow the problem with my approach is I am hogging up a bunch of memory, when I want to use disk instead.

Comment: Just write to your `OutputStream`, `flush()` it, and empty your List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but generally, this is how you write data "on the fly" to disk.

- Open output file
- While generating data, write row or buffer to output file
- Close output file

Edited to answer questions in comment.

> I want the data to be streamed to the disk as the application is running, and for data not to be lost per se if the app crashed in the middle of execution.

Well, you could lose the last row or buffer if the application crashes.  You use the finally method to make sure you close the output file, even if the application crashes.

> Can you provide a quick code sample?

Sure.

```
public void writeOutput() {
    boolean processRunning = true;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        while (processRunning) {
            String s = generateOutput();
            bufferedWriter.write(s);
            if (s.equals("finished")) {
                processRunning = false;
            }
        }
        bufferedWriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know off hand, when you are programming in C or C++, the file does not actually appear to the user until the `fp.close();` is called.  What I am trying to get at in Java, is this the same?  I want the data to be streamed to the disk as the application is running, and for data not to be lost per se if the app crashed in the middle of execution.  Can you provide a quick code sample?  Or is it just the standard `write()` method?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).

You can force data you write to be actually flushed onto the disk using the `force()` method.

Here's a usage example:

```
RandomAccessFile file = null;

try {
    file = new RandomAccessFile("/home/user/mytempfile", "rw");
    FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        file.writeUTF("Hello");
        channel.force(true);
    }
} finally {
    if (file != null) {
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the

java.io.FileStream and
java.io.BufferedWriter

libraries.

Here is a quick setup to let you start playing with them:

```
import java.io.*;

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\junkdirectory\\textdump.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

out.write("This is a test!!");
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to dump an ArrayList to a file:

**At the construction ro App start time:**

```
final ObjectOutputStream fos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                                   new FileOutputStream("data.dump", true));
```

**At the time of writing data to file:**

```
try {
    fos.writeObject(list); // write your list to file
    fos.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**When you don't need file anymore (at the end):**

```
fos.close(); // surround with try-catch block
```